# SVG: make an element's property dependent on a property of another element

Tags: variables, svg, properties, reference

I have a simple SVG tree where I want the x property of rect2 to be dependent (referencing) on the width of rect1:

```
<rect id="rect1" style="fill:black" x="35" y="0" width="30" height="40" />
<rect id="rect2" style="fill:black" x="**rect1.width**" y="40" width="26" height="10" />
```

Is something like that possible in SVG, I couldn't find it in yahoogle or the SVG reference.

Another approach would be variables

```
**var widthOfRect1 = 30**
<rect id="rect1" style="fill:black" x="35" y="0" width="widthOfRect1" height="40" />
<rect id="rect2" style="fill:black" x="widthOfRect1" y="40" width="26" height="10" />
```

Is there a way to do that? I know you can pass in parameters, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Ideas?

Comment: You may want to check if https://github.com/indus/VLEX does what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option of doing this with the mutation events.

Created fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Afhmn/

As the width of the rect1 increases the x of the rect2 is changed inside the `DOMAttrModified` handler.

Comment: Right, that'll work. Thanks, this will make me end up with a lot of extra script, though. I hoped there was a more native SVG solution to this. Maybe there isn't?